# How to know the program that called my program by vb6 , or c#?

Tags: c#, api, vb6

I write a program(A) , that read information from another program(B).  When B call A. How to find out the hwnd of B? 
With A written by vb6 or c#. Can i use API or other way?

Thanks so much

Comment: Maybe you can provide some code or something, this is a very confusing/conflicting question :) sorry

Comment: Also vb6 and c# are different languages as I am sure you are aware.

Comment: I'm using vb6 write a software read excel cells. It like a plugins.  Excel can shell my software. But when many the excel programs running. I can't determine what shelled my program. Because that i can't read exactly information

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, you should use another approach.

Comment: With regards to the Excel comment, are you using VB6 or VBA?

Comment: I'm using vb6, and write a software like plugins.  It can be shelled from excel

Comment: What exact are you doing? Is your program a "standalone" executable callend by excel or is it an ActiveX component used by excel?

Comment: You cannot determine the program that started yours with certainty. You can get your parent process ID, but these are reused by windows. If there is any length of time the parent process ID may point to a different program.

Comment: In your Excel macro that shells your VB6/C# app just pass Excel's form `hWnd` or Excel's `ProcessID` as a command-line parameter like `/hwnd:54321` or `/pid:12345` and then expect/process it in your VB6/C# app.

Answer (score 1):

How about the program B send your own process id when calls A?

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

    Sub execute()

        Dim pid As Integer
        pid = GetCurrentProcessId()

        'Call Program A Pass pid to your Program

    End Sub
```

This is a sample that get Excel processID and you can now call a program, sending it as parameter. The program is now identified.